# Unable to get a single game from a list of games using GET - FLASK and POSTMAN

Tags: python, flask, postman

I am currently learning Python FLASK. I am able to display all the games using GET. However, I want to display a specific game using GET as well.

When I run my API on postman, it returns an error 404 NOT FOUND. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

My game model:

```
def get_game(gamename):
    """
    Returns a game specified from the database if it exists.
    """
    return mongo.db.games.find_one({'gamename': gamename})
```

The following is my get_game() function to get a specific game instead of all games:

```
def get_game(gamename):
    game = game_model.get_game(gamename)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        game = request.get_json()
        return jsonify(game)
```

My API:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/games/<gamename>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNoPj.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is one example

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

products = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Product 1'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Product 2'}
]

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/products')
def get_products():
    return jsonify(products)


@app.route('/product/<int:id>')
def get_product(id):
    product_list = [product for product in products if product['id'] == id]
    if len(product_list) == 0:
        return f'Product with id {id} not found', 404
    return jsonify(product_list[0])
```

Also, I have found another example [here](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/flask-python-mongodb/#reading-a-single-cocktail).

```py
@app.route("/api/games/<string:gamename>", methods=["GET"])
def get_game(gamename):
    game_name = games.find_one_or_404({"gamename": gamename})
    return YourModel(**game_name).to_json()
```